# ElasticSearch / Ruby - Date Histogram Format Returned?

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, tire

I've got an ElasticSearch model (persisted by Tire, no ActiveRecord).  If I query it, i get some results with some facets (as expected).

```
The format is: 

class Mention
  include Tire::Model::Persistence
  index_name 'mentions'

  # basic display attributes
  property :created_at, :type => 'date'
end
```

The query returns results fine. When I check the dates returned, I get back a string.

```
1.9.2p320 :046 > a.results[0].created_at
 => "2012-12-26T02:55:50+01:00" 
1.9.2p320 :047 > a.results[0].created_at.class
 => String 
1.9.2p320 :048 > a.results[1].created_at
 => "2012-12-26T02:55:50+01:00" 
1.9.2p320 :049 > a.results[2].created_at
 => "2012-12-26T02:56:33+01:00" 
1.9.2p320 :050 > a.results[2].created_at.class
 => String
```

I have a simple facet that returns the date_histogram, simply to retrieve the volume of results by day that match the query.  Formatted like so:

```
  facet 'volumes' do 
    date :created_at
  end
```

This, unfortunately, seems to return a crazy Unix timestamp.

```
1.9.2p320 :069 > d = a.helper.facets["volumes"]["entries"][0]["time"].to_s
 => "1356307200000" 
1.9.2p320 :070 > d.class
 => String 
1.9.2p320 :071 > Date.strptime(d, "%s")
 => Sun, 31 Aug 44949 
1.9.2p320 :072 >
```

I've got to be doing something wrong. Am I? If so, what?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tire doesn't manipulate the facet responses, so it returns the raw value returned by Elasticsearch.

For `date_histogram` facet, the timestamp is returned as a number of *milliseconds* since epoch. Ruby, on the other hand, works with [*seconds* since epoch](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-to_i).

The easiest thing you can do is to simply divide by 1000:

```
>> d = a.helper.facets["volumes"]["entries"][0]["time"].to_i
=> 1356307200000
>> Time.at(d/1000)
=> 2012-12-24 01:00:00 +0100
```

Arguably, *Tire* could/should do the conversion for you here.